# Using Row/Column values from a table to print corresponding location value into array?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a csv file with headers titled Row, Column, and ID number. There are a total of 10 rows, 15 columns (making a total of 165 entries), each with a corresponding ID number specific to the location on the 10x15 grid surface [Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQhhW.png). Using the specific row/column values, I'd like to fill an array with the corresponding ID number to the specified location in the grid. So far I have created a 10x15 array of zeros and would like to replace those values with the ID numbers at the correct location. Fairly new to python so apologies if this is not explained great, but any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What kind of an array do you want to get? In case a pandas DataFrame works for you, you can load it directly as `df = pd.read_csv(filename)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your ids are integers, you could just store them into a numpy array.
You could use

`id_array = np.genfromtxt('your_file.csv', delimiter = ',')`

or else used pandas library

`import pandas as pd`

`df=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')`

you can convert it into numpy using 
`df.to_numpy()`

Your id array will be a 3D array just, iterate over its rows to populate your grid array.

```
 for row in range(id_array.shape[0]): 
      grid_array[id_array[row][0]][id_array[row][1]] = id_array[row][2]
```

Or else you can do this also,

```
rows = id_array[:,0]
cols = id_array[:,1]
grid_arr[rows,cols] = id_array[:,2]
```

Comment: From my understanding, both functions read in the csv as an array, correct? From there is there a way to return the ID number in the correct location of a new 10x15 array? For example, from the snip you will see an entry reading row 2, column 7, that has an ID number of 6. Can 6 then be placed in that coordinate location of the 10x15 array?

Comment: Yes, once you get the id array, just use

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Anurag Reddy, I get the following error from executing the code: IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type.

Comment: Just typecast them to integer using `id_array.astype(int)`